# Исправление Bootstrap верстки

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Html:

```html
echo '<div class="row">';

  while($data = mysql_fetch_array($pa)){ 
   $fiya = number_format($data['fiyat'], 0, ' ', ' ');
   $fiyat = '<div class="fiyat">'.$fiya.'</div>';
   $name = mb_substr($data['name'], 0, 45, 'UTF-8') . '...';
echo '
 <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="'.$data['img'].'">


<div class="tovarfooter"><div class="text">'.$name.'</div>
 <div class="bilgi">
  <div class="fiyat">'.$fiyat.' <img src="../tl.png" width="9" height="10"></img></div>
  <div class="bilgisag">'.$data['il'].'/'.$data['ilce'].'</div>
 </div>
</div>


    </a>
 </div>
  ';
echo '</div>';
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно на изображении, На 4 том блоке "TEST1..." имя товара меньше чем другие и составляет одну строку, из за этого портится снизу блоки как всё это исправить?

А точнее как правельно создать такие блоки адаптивные по вертикали и горизонтали?

Comment: покажите вашу разметку.

Comment: напишите полный код для блоков(с текстом и изображениями), в т.ч. с css(если используете доп. стили).

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблемы с помощью nth-child:
HTML:
`<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-16  col-md-4 col-lg-3">
</div>...
</div>`

@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 992px) {
.col-sm-6:nth-child(2n+1)
{
clear: left;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) and (max-width : 1200px){
.col-md-4:nth-child(3n+1)
{
clear: left;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px){
.col-lg-3:nth-child(4n+1)
{
clear: left;
}
}